# Where did the script menu go in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

I always love the script menu from Xcode and the ability to automatically generate accessor methods definition und declaration. But it looks like in Xcode4 there is no such thing anymore. I know I can use properties but sometimes accessor methods are still needed. Any other way to create them automatically?

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 4 now has "Behaviors", under the "Xcode" menu.  You can create custom behaviors here, which can be used to execute scripts (among other things).

[image: Screenshot of Behaviors panel]

[image: Screenshot of Behaviors menu]

Comment: How can you make it run a script?  I do NOT see that as an option on the Behaviors panel..

Comment: @alexgray: Near the bottom of the Behaviors editor, there's a "Run" checkbox.  I just added a screenshot highlighting this.

Answer (score 2):

See https://devforums.apple.com/message/380673#380673

Comment: What is this? It takes me to a blank "Sent Invitations" page.

Comment: It´s a link to a tip that says: “As far as I know it's gone. I hope they bring it back before the final release. Until then your only option is to drop it in ~/Library/Scripts and then go to File > Services > Service Preferences... and set a keyboard shortcut.” which I didn't post at the time because of the NDA.